# SpeechRecognizer WinRT unwanted audio output

Tags: audio, windows-runtime, speech-recognition

I am writing a WinRT app, testing it in VS 2015, x86 debug.  I am getting 
unwanted audio output that is not created by my application.  Here is my code:

```
using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition;
SpeechRecognitionResult result = await recEngine.RecognizeAsync(); 
  //recEngine is of type SpeechRecognizer; using dictation grammar.
if (result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Rejected)
    return;
if (result.RawConfidence < .60)
    return;
//proceed to process the speech-to-text in the result......
```

If I just return (have unrecognized speech), I do not get the audio output: fine. If I am successful in recognizing the speech, I process it in my app, but I also get the following audio output (in my desktop speakers):

"I do not recognize the command. Please try again".

Where is this coming from and how do I suppress it?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my mistake.  I found the audio output (that I created myself).